# Maven Missing artifact org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:11-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, geotools

Hello I am trying to write a simple geotools project with maven. Actually I am very new to maven. I opened new maven project I set the setting and write some code. As I know maven should download and install the needed jar files of geotools. But A am getting "Missing artifact org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:11-SNAPSHOT" error and I cannot understand why is that.

My working envirement:

Eclipse Kepler,
Jdk 6,
Maven-Latest release,
Geotools-Latest release

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>tutorial</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>11-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Here is my Quickstart class

```
    package org.geotools.tutorial;

import java.io.File;

import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;

/**
 * Prompts the user for a shapefile and displays the contents on the screen in a map frame.
 * <p>
 * This is the GeoTools Quickstart application used in documentationa and tutorials. *
 */
public class Quickstart {

    /**
     * GeoTools Quickstart demo application. Prompts the user for a shapefile and displays its
     * contents on the screen in a map frame
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // display a data store file chooser dialog for shapefiles
        File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
        if (file == null) {
            return;
        }

        FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

        // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
        MapContent map = new MapContent();
        map.setTitle("Quickstart");

        Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
        Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
        map.addLayer(layer);

        // Now display the map
        JMapFrame.showMap(map);
    }

}
```

I just wrote the codes I didn't download or install any jars. I opened the project as maven project. I wonder when and how maven is downloading and installing jars?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing repository URL with: http://repo.opengeo.org/

Comment: I know this is an old post, but that URL is no longer active FYI.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is really old, but still comes up first when searching for the issue. The URL changed again, it is now:

```
<repository>
    <id>osgeo</id>
    <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
  </repository>
```

or if you want to enable snapshots:

```
  <repository>
    <id>osgeo</id>
    <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
    <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
  </repository>
```

See also the [Eclipse Quickstart guide on the project website](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html).

Comment: Works fine to me!

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Please remove this

Answer (score 2):

Maven downloading and putting jars to local repository during one of its lifecycle phases im not sure which one, but if you run `mvn clean install` it should download all jars required by your project.

Comment: Should I write a command in command window "mvn claen install", or I should do it somehow diffrent ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to have maven bin directory added to system PATH variable.

Comment: Note that this should be run from your project directory.

Answer (score 2):

For me, adding following fixed the problem. It try to get GeoTools from following repo since it is not on maven central.

```
<repository>
    <id>osgeo</id>
    <name>Geotools repository</name>
    <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: This one is now defunct

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old post, but I had this problem recently and solved it by replacing

`http://repo.opengeo.org/` with  `http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/`

Comment: Where should I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, replacing repository with URL  "http://repo.opengeo.org/" works for me!